# Why is the operator overloading not performing properly?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am getting a compilation error when  overloading the operator ++ in C++. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Age{
    private:
        int age;
    public:
        Age(int age): age(age){

        }

        Age& operator++(){
            Age ages(this->age + 1);
            return ages;
        }

        int getAge(){
            return age;
        }
};


int main(){

    Age myAge(20);
    Age nextAge = myAge++;
    cout << nextAge.getAge() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`operator++()` defines the pre-increment operator.

To define post-increment you need to declare `operator++(int)`

The `int` parameter is not actually used, but there needs to be some syntactical way to distinguish pre-increment and post-increment overloads, so they have different signatures.

You have other problems though: your operator doesn't modify `*this` it only modifies a local variable, and it returns a reference to that local, which will lead to undefined behaviour when you try to access the return value.

You probably want to define a pre-increment which modifies `*this` and returns a reference:

```
    Age& operator++(){
        this->age += 1;
        return *this;
    }
```

and then define post-increment in terms of that, creating a copy and returning it by value:

```
    Age operator++(int){
        Age age(*this);    // make a copy of the current value
        ++*this;           // update the current value
        return age;        // return the copy
    }
```

You're also using it strangely:

```
Age nextAge = myAge++;
```

The `nextAge` variable will **not** be the next age, it will be the old value of `myAge`, and `myAge` will be incremented to the next value. Try changing your program to use simple `int` variables and see how the `++` operator behaves.

There is no point trying to create your own `operator++` overload if you don't understand what the operator does!

Maybe what you really want is just `operator+` so you can write:

```
Age nextAge = myAge + 1;
```

There are several ways to define that `operator+` function.  Given the pre-increment operator above you could define that like this, as a non-member function:

```
Age operator+(const Age& age, int n) {
    Age newAge(age);
    while (n--) {
        ++newAge;
    }
    return newAge;
}
```

Or more efficiently as a (const) member function:

```
Age operator+(int n) const {
    Age newAge(*this);
    newAge->age += n;
    return newAge;
}
```

Comment: @coder12345, yes, see my updated answer. To have the conventional semantics post-increment **must** return a copy, because you can't return a reference to a local and you can't return a reference to `*this` (because it's been modified already).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be returning a reference to a local variable in the `operator++` overload.  That will result in undefined behavior.  Return by value in this case.

Comment: No, pre-increment this should return by reference, and the body should be `++age; return *this;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, but he's trying to use it as post-increment

Comment: @JonathanWakely Nonetheless it is a pre-increment overload as written. The answer I am commenting on reads as if the only change required is to return by value instead of returning by reference, which is incorrect. (it should either return by value *and* change to overloading post-increment; or return by reference and remain with the existing signature, or both as suggested by your answer)

Answer (score 0):

The pre-increment operator should look like this:

```
Age& operator++()
{
    ++(this->age);
    return *this; // you can safely return a reference to the object pointed by "this"
}
```

The post-increment operator should look like this:

```
Age operator++(int) // the int argument is merely to distinguis the two operators - it has no other use
{
    Age previousAge( this->age ); // the post-increment operator must return the value before incementation
    ++(this->age);
    return previousAge; // you can safely return a copy of a local variable
}
```

Also, the use of "this" would not be needed if the member variable used the [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).